# Android Application not running (Error : Application stopped running unexpectedly. Please Try Again)

Tags: android

This is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SMS"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the XML file (main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Enter the phone number of recipient"
        />     
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:text="Message"
        />     
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:gravity="top"         
        />          
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send SMS"
        />    
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the java file (SMS.java):-

```
package net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

public class SMS extends Activity 
{
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);


        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0) {
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });        
    } 
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
    }   
}
```

The error portion :-

```
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging/net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging.SMS}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging.SMS.onCreate(SMS.java:31)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-26 23:06:41.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(411):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: The Emulator on which the error is occurring is Targeted to Android 2.3.3 ver. 10 rev 2 (GingerBread). Sorry if the question is unstructured/non detailed

Comment: can you debug the program? from the log I conclude the exception goes on  btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ;

Comment: What exactly is happening on line 31? This is your problem: at net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging.SMS.onCreate(SMS.java:31)

Comment: I just tried your code and it works fine there is no error.

Comment: put break point at sendSMS function , give values of phoneNo, message and debug program. If your execution cant reach there just check your edit text component for values. Try it. :)

Comment: May I suggest cleaning your project? It seems that the R.java got out of sync.

Comment: I dont know how but it started running now.. (probably after restarting the OS), but the SMS is not getting delivered to another Emulator using this SMS Application. On the Emulator where the application is installed (5554, for ex.) is able to send (to 5556) and showing that SMS send successfully but on the other emulator(5556) its not getting delivered. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu're getting a NullPointerException at line 31 which is where btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(

Probably the view with the id wasn't found.

as a workaround add

```
if (btnSendSMS != null) {
   btnSendSMS.setOnClickLi......
}
```

Comment: I dont know how but it started running now.. (probably after restarting the OS), but the SMS is not getting delivered to another Emulator using this SMS Application. On the Emulator where the application is installed (5554, for ex.) is able to send (to 5556) and showing that SMS send successfully but on the other emulator(5556) its not getting delivered. Please help.